# Git push remote branch is forbidden, because to binary file

Tags: git

**$** git push origin dev_1:feat/i18n

git push log

```
  Enumerating objects: 9, done.
  Counting objects: 100% (9/9), done.
  Delta compression using up to 12 threads
  Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
  Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 20.44 KiB | 872.00 KiB/s, done.
  Total 5 (delta 4), reused 1 (delta 1)
  remote: Start Git Hooks Checking                                                [FAILED]
  remote: Error: Binary file '[mypath]__init__.pyc' is forbidden
  To [mypath]
   ! [remote rejected] dev_1 -> feat/i18n (pre-receive hook declined)
  error: failed to push some refs to '[mypath]'
```

I don't rewite the pyc file in my local branch, I just cloned the project and changed a file that is not related to pyc.

I try `git checkout --ours[mypath]__init__.pyc`

I get the output:

Updated 0 paths from the index

Then git push agian, this error still exists.

Comment: See what files you have changed in the new commits: `git fetch origin feat/i18n && git diff FETCH_HEAD..dev_1 --name-status`.

Comment: @ElpieKay without pyc file
 M       src/package.json

Comment: What's the output of `git log --name-status -- [mypath]__init__.pyc`? There are spaces around `--`. You can find who introduced this file in which commit.

Comment: I commit it on January 11th.These pyc files were unfamiliar to me and I submitted them without checking.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.

The cause of this problem is that the `feat/i18n` branch remote repository does not exist,then this branch will verify all files.

Does not support pyc file submission is the access control configured after I submitted this code, so I can push branch in first time.